# Problem with C# MySQL Connection

Tags: mysql, gtk, database, monodevelop, c#

Hello everybody i have a MySQL connection problem in C#. This is my problem in the picture. thanks for help me. 
[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

What a hideous sidebar, hahaha, I'm sorry.

The problem is that the MySQL client in your C# program cannot connect to the MySQL server. Are you able to log into the MySQL server yourself? You may be connecting from another machine with a user that is only locally available.

Please check the permissions/credentials of the user you're trying to log in to your server as.

Also check that the server is online, and on what ip/host/domain/port it is running.

This is a typical connection problem. There is nothing wrong with MonoDevelop, or the libraries it uses. It is your configuration, code and/or system that produces this error, so without more information on the set-up there is nothing more I/we can help with right now.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, did you install the MySQL connector/NET?

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/mysql/

Download link:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Good luck!

Comment: thanks it's running in Console mode. but in GTK  it dosen't , help me please .

Comment: Sounds a bit strange and a different problem. But try to run when targeting x86 (32-bit).